# How to connect pgAdmin4 in Docker container to existing AWS RDS database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, pgadmin-4

I pulled the image "dpage/pgadmin4" and ran with the following:

```
sudo docker run --name "pgadmin" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=<me@domain.com>" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=<mypassword>" -e "PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5050" -p 5050:5050 -p 5432:5432 -d dpage/pgadmin4 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

I am able to access the container in my browser at localhost:5050

I tried creating a server in pgAdmin how I would have with a local install (screenshot) but it cannot connect to our database endpoint.
[image: server registration on pgAdmin: connection tab]

I receive the following error message:

> Unable to connect to server: could not translate host name "[endpoint
> ]" to address: Try again

I suspect I need to create a docker network, but cannot find the config for this. What am I missing to be able to get the container to connect to our AWS database?

Comment: How is this related to programming? --- "*has been a challenge*" is no helpful problem description. We need at least the database configuration added to pgadmin4 and an error message to diagnose the problem. Error logs from the pgadmin4 container might also be useful.

Comment: What is your database endpoint? How would you connect to it using `psql` from the command line? Does that work when you run it on the same host on which you're trying to set up the pgadmin4 container?

Comment: edited to add requested info and connecting via psql works on the same host running the pgadmin4 container as follows:

psql \
   --host=<DB instance endpoint> \
   --port=5432 \
   --username=<username> \
   --password \
   --dbname=<database name>